# Windows cache usage increases for files creation program written in C

Tags: c++, c, windows

I have a small test program that creates millions of files (for testing purposes) in thousands of folders. It is C code with `fopen` and `fclose` calls.

This code runs fine on Linux ([RHEL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux), [SUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SUSE_Linux_distributions)), but on Windows the memory usage increases as the number of files to create increases (near a million files). The system memory usage increases 
to nearly 8 GB (system capacity) and the program becomes extremely slow (I assume due to swapping in and out of pages).

At this time the program's memory requirements remain constant at around few MBs though (which is expected). I observed that the cache usage in the memory increases rapidly as the program progresses and keeps growing through the life of the program. How can I tell Windows not to cache these files or folders and is it even possible?

Comment: Could you share your small test program ?

Comment: Does the process memory also increases on windows as the program runs?

Comment: @steve Nope the process memory stays the same. I am going to try to use the Win 32 API.

Comment: code is pasted at "http://pastebin.com/nUfSVe82"

Comment: It is "normal, expected" behaviour to cache data that you access, and that is harmless. Memory used for cache is generally better than memory that is unused, and cache does normally _not_ impact performance in any way. If the system needs more memory, it just throws the oldest cache entries away. The OS will __never__ start swapping in order to satisfy cache, that would be entirely stupid -- not going to happen.

Comment: @Damon, I agree but I don't understand why does the system memory usage increases constantly despite of the fact that the memory usage for process remains the same. At one stage there is nothing remaining as "available" and very little in "cached". The system memory just climbs up for no reason.

Comment: @JonCage I had to delete the code, sorry! :(...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess, but you might just be trashing/filling the file cache with files that do not need to be used again. This would slow down the system, because it must read files from disk. Also the disk would be in use while it was doing this.

You could try using the [Win32 API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API) and CreateFile with the file flag FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING so that is does not cache files.

Comment: I read at the following [link] (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that working with these kind of files requires alignment and access requirements. I am not sure if the program can work under those strict norms, I am thinking of using "FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH" as it uses cache but it written to the disk right away.

Comment: That might slow down the program even further. Every write will now have to wait for the physical hard disk head to move. Do try, but don't expect miracles.